# Softlayer API: how to get machine password

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I know I can use SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password to retrieve/update OS password value in Softlayer's database, is there an API to get the password for the machine? which is the machine logon password?

Thank you,

Q.Z.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following request:

**For Virtual Servers:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/111111/getObject?objectMask=mask[operatingSystem[passwords]]
```

**For Bare Metal Servers:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/111111/getObject?objectMask=mask[operatingSystem[passwords]]
```

**Replace:** **$user**, **$apiKey** and **111111** with your own information.

It will display the username and password for the machine

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The API you posted retrieves Virtual Severs or Bare Metal Servers's OS password, it is not machine password, which is used to logon to machine.

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding, but are you able to get this user/password in [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/)? Could you provide the steps that you followed for it? What are you meaning with machine?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Ruber. There are 2 passwords when an instance is created which are the same initially: VS - KVM console (Xen - vnc root user for given port of instance) and VS - OS  (root / Administrator). User can logon to Softlayer portal to update the second password, which results that there is no way for user to know the first password.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure about this kind of instances, are you able to order one of this currently? or maybe can you provide me an id of it, in order that I can look for it?

Comment: I asked Softlayer support team. Due to security concern, SL doesn't provide API to retrieve the password I want. Thank you for your reply, Ruber!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Python API, you can retrieve the password with the following function

*def get_instance Found at: SoftLayer.managers.vs*

Example:

```
vs_unit_info = SoftLayer.VSManager(sl_client).get_instance(vs_unit_id, mask="fullyQualifiedDomainName, primaryIpAddress, operatingSystem.passwords.username, operatingSystem.passwords.password")
```